# Python - TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'

Tags: python, computer-vision

I understand that variations this question has been answered for other people. But none of the solutions that worked for them have worked for me. So I've come to ask for help.

I get the error on line 69. That is, cv2.imshow("G image1", img1_G). I'd probably get it on line 72 as well, since the code for those two is basically the same, but my program doesn't get that far.

Please help.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def apply_filter(img, kernel):
    # Create a 2D output array with all values set to 0
    filtered_img = np.zeros_like(img)

    # Create a new 2D array that is the same as the original input image, but with an edge of zeroes.
    # That will allows us to use the filter on every pixel of the original image.
    # The edge of zeros will be cut off when we write the filtered values into our filtered_img
    # For a 3x3 filter, the edge is just one zero thick. So the height and width both increase by just two total.
    padded_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0] + 2, img.shape[1] + 2))
    padded_img[1: -1, 1: -1] = img

    # Loop through the entire img
    for row in range(img.shape[0]):
        for col in range(img.shape[1]):
            # Write new value to filtered_img
            filtered_img[row, col] = (kernel * padded_img[row: row + 3, col: col + 3]).sum()

    return filtered_img


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Take in the images. Both img variables will be 2D arrays.
    img1 = cv2.imread('image1.png', 0)
    img2 = cv2.imread('image2.png', 0)

    # Create my Gx filter array
    Gx = [
        [-1, 0, 1],
        [-2, 0, 1],
        [-1, 0, 1]
    ]

    # Create my Gy filter array
    Gy = [
        [-1, -2, -1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 1]
    ]

    # Store the Gx and Gy filtered arrays
    filtered_img1_Gx = apply_filter(img1, Gx)
    filtered_img1_Gy = apply_filter(img1, Gy)

    # Create a final product for img1
    img1_G = np.sqrt(np.square(filtered_img1_Gx) + np.square(filtered_img1_Gy))
    img1_G *= 255.0 / img1_G.max()
    img1_G = np.array(img1_G)

    # Store the Gx and Gy filtered arrays
    filtered_img2_Gx = apply_filter(img2, Gx)
    filtered_img2_Gy = apply_filter(img2, Gy)

    # Create a final product for img2
    img2_G = np.sqrt(np.square(filtered_img2_Gx) + np.square(filtered_img2_Gy))
    img2_G *= 255.0 / img2_G.max()
    img2_G = np.array(img2_G)

    # Display the original images
    cv2.imshow("Original image1", img1)
    cv2.imshow("Original image2", img2)

    # Display the filtered images
    cv2.imshow("Gx image1", filtered_img1_Gx)
    cv2.imshow("Gy image1", filtered_img1_Gy)
    # This is where I get the error
    cv2.imshow("G image1", img1_G)

    cv2.imshow("Gx image2", filtered_img2_Gx)
    cv2.imshow("Gy image2", filtered_img2_Gy)
    cv2.imshow("G image2", img2_G)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: `img1_G` and `img2_G` have type `np.float16` when reaching the mentioned line(s) (and OpenCV doesn't support that type for `cv2.imshow`; the error message is not that clear here), but have values in range `0.0 ... 255.0`. So, the fastest fix would be something like `cv2.imshow("G image1", img1_G.astype(np.uint8))`.

Comment: It works and it's beautiful! Thank you so very much.